# ReSharper Warning: Base Class [NotNull] While Derived Class Property [CanBeNull] Conflict

Tags: c#, overriding, resharper, nullable

Consider the following C#.Net code:

```
using System.Xml;

internal class MyXmlReaderClass : XmlReader
{
    private readonly XmlReader _innerReader;

    public MyXmlReaderClass(...other_parameters... , XmlReader innerReader)
    {
        _innerReader = innerReader;
    }
    //... lots of code has been left out, here ...

    public override string LocalName
    {
        get { return _innerReader.LocalName; }
    }
    //... lots more code has been left out, here ... 
}
```

In the property, `LocalName`, ReSharper places an underline under the type, `string`, with the warning, *'string' is (explicitly or implicitly) [NotNull]*.

I thought that I understood the concept in play regarding nullable objects.  I have been able to refactor most of these issues out of my code, except in this case.

If I understand my world correctly, the base class (XmlReader) is what ReSharper identifies as `[NotNull]`.  That means that ReSharper believes that my override of the property could possibly return a null while the base never returns a null.

I am having a difficult time wrapping my mind around how I could override the base class property `LocalName` with some sort of override, such that there is no conflict in the property between the base class and the derived class.

My question is a multiple-part, "What exactly is ReSharper identifying, and how do I fix the inconsistency?"

Yes, I have searched high and low through StackOverflow and used Google yet cannot find this specific example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a ReSharper warning, it's a ["type highlighting" of the Implicit Nullability extension](https://github.com/ulrichb/ImplicitNullability/#type-highlighting).

> What exactly is ReSharper identifying?

The highlighting *informs* you that your member's return type is implicitly [NotNull] because the base member is [NotNull].

The base member, `XmlReader.LocalName`, is [NotNull] because of an [External Annotation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__External_Annotations.html) provided by ReSharper.

> How do I fix the inconsistency?

You don't have to fix it, because it's no warning/suggestion. It's just a highlighting.

If you don't like this highlighting you can disable it in the R# options on the Implicit Nullability page.